# ScrollView in second panel not working

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, sliding

I have an `Activity` that uses [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). Now, everything works perfect. However, I would like to add a `ScrollView` on my second panel to add the same functionality like [Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) or Google Music:

For instance,

[image]

When the user has a list of directions, he/she may pull up the drawer and scroll the complete instructions.

Now, my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_slide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/slide_up"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_nutrition_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

This, displays fine my content, but does not add the scroll view for the second panel.
 What can I do?

**Note**: According to the documentation of [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), there can only be two children under its view. I use a `LinearLayout` as the second child because its the only way that I have found to display the drawer. For instance, that `TextView` would be in the place of the content of the estimated time (drawer) from Maps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding an `id` to the `Parent` of the Title, and adding this to my code:

```
layout.setDragView((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrolled_view));
```

New `.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrolled_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_slide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/slide_up"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_nutrition_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of second `scrollview` should be `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    take one RelativeLayout in com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout and set property layout_above="yoursecondLinearlayout" to First ScrollView and second child LinearLayout to set property alignParentBottom=true. thats it....
See below code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >
     **<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >**
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        **android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout1"**>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        **android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"**
        **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_slide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/slide_up"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
                android:id="@+id/food_nutrition_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```